# Ubuntu Certified hardware HP MicroServer G7 N54L

Tags: hp

Why is the HP MicroServer G7 N54L not on the Ubuntu Certified hardware list?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't on the list because it isn't certified. That's has two root causes:

- HP hasn't submitted it for certification, or
- It failed testing.

Most importantly, certification doesn't mean it neccessarily will or won't work. Many people run Ubuntu on the HP Microservers so I think despite the lack of certification, you plunge on and not worry about it too much.